# Как определить, является ли заданная строка десятичным представлением натурального числа от 1 до 2^64-1 включительно?

Tags: c, golang

Еще условие: строка не должна начинаться с "0".

Например:

- `"0"` – нет
- `"1"` – да
- `"07"` – нет
- `"18446744073709551615"` (2<sup>64</sup> − 1) – да
- `"18446744073709551616"` (2<sup>64</sup>) – нет

Comment: atoi() или его заменители плюс проверка на ноль с учетом кол-ва разрядов.

Comment: @alexolut, но atoi() с заменителями примут и отрицательное число, кроме того, они и "1aaa" посчитают за 1, а мне это не подходит.

Comment: может `itoa(atoi(строка)) == строка`

Comment: @Alexander Zonov: Ну так не используйте `atoi`. `atoi` - функция, которую не принято даже упоминать в компетентном программистском обществе. Функции группы `ato...` - не используются. Правильная функция называется `strtoull`. А после нее вы и проверить все что надо сможете. Включая `1aaa`. Разве что на `-` может придется проверить самостоятельно.

Comment: @AnT,  спасибо, это как раз то, что нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как [вариант](https://play.golang.org/p/tDNix-c2_nB):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func checkStr(str string) bool {

    if strings.TrimPrefix(str, "0") != str {
        fmt.Println("Начинается с 0")
        return false
    }
    if _, err := strconv.ParseUint(str, 10, 64); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(checkStr("18446744073709551615"))
    fmt.Println(checkStr("18446744073709551616"))
    fmt.Println(checkStr("1b"))
    fmt.Println(checkStr("-1234567"))
    fmt.Println(checkStr("07"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая, что требуется особое поведение для `0`, `-`, пробелов, пределов (2<sup>64</sup>-1), конца строки — не сложнее с нуля распознавание строки как натурального числа реализовать:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_posint64(const char* s)
{
  if (!s || !*s || !('1' <= *s && *s <= '9'))
    return false;

  uint64_t n = *s++ - '0';
  for ( ; *s; ++s) {
    if (*s < '0' || *s > '9'
        || n > UINT64_MAX / 10
        || (uint64_t)(*s - '0') > (UINT64_MAX - 10*n))
      return false;

    n = 10*n + (*s - '0');
  }
  return true;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/TQ71yV).

Answer (score 1):

Возможный вариант на си:

```
const static int WIDTH = 21;

void f(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    if (len == 0) {
        printf("%*s: empty string\n", WIDTH, s);
        return;
    }
    if (s[0] == '0') {
        printf("%*s: starts with zero\n", WIDTH, s);
        return;
    }
    if (s[0] == '-') {
        printf("%*s: negative\n", WIDTH, s);
        return;
    }
    char *last = &s[len];
    char *newlast = last;
    uint64_t n = strtoull(s, &newlast, 10);
    if (errno != 0) {
        printf("%*s: error: %s\n", WIDTH, s, strerror(errno));
        errno = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (last != newlast) {
        printf("%*s: extra characters: %s\n", WIDTH, s, newlast);
        return;
    }
    printf("%*s: number %lu\n", WIDTH, s, n);
}
```

Comment: это разрешает `"  0"`, а должно запрещать. 2- %lu -> %llu 3- в принципе ULLONG_MAX может быть больше `UINT64_MAX`

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то пригодится еще один вариант на C. Число 2<sup>16</sup> − 1 записано как строка-шаблон. Если в какой-то позиции цифра во входной строке меньше, чем в шаблоне, то приемлемо еще столько же любых цифр, сколько осталось до конца шаблона. Если больше, то на одну меньше. Если равна, то проверяем следующие цифры строки и шаблона.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int validate_index(const char *str)
{

    const char *template = "18446744073709551615";
    static int length = 0;
    if (length == 0) length = strlen(template);
    int i, length2 = length;

    // строка пустая или начинается с цифры 0
    if (str[0] == '\0' || str[0] == '0') return 0;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

        char c = str[i];

        // строка закончена
        if (c == '\0') return -1;

        // символ не цифра
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') return i;

        // сравнение с шаблоном
        if (c == template[i]) continue;
        if (c > template[i]) length2--;

        break;

    }

    for (; i < length2; i++)
    {

        char c = str[i];

        // строка закончена
        if (c == '\0') return -1;

        // символ не цифра
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') return i;

    }

    // строка не закончена
    if (str[i] != '\0') return i;

    return -1;

}

int main()
{

    const char *strs[] = {
        "0",
        "1",
        "07",
        "1aaa",
        "12345",
        "18446744073709551614",
        "18446744073709551615",
        "18446744073709551616",
        "184467440737095516150",
        "28446744073709551615",
        "18446744074709551615",
    };

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof strs / sizeof *strs; i++)
    {
        int r = validate_index(strs[i]);
        if (r == -1)
            printf("\"%s\" - yes\n", strs[i]);
        else
            printf("\"%.*s[%c]%s\" - no\n", r, strs[i], strs[i][r], &strs[i][r+1]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Результат:

```
"[0]" - no
"1" - yes
"[0]7" - no
"1[a]aa" - no
"12345" - yes
"18446744073709551614" - yes
"18446744073709551615" - yes
"1844674407370955161[6]" - no
"18446744073709551615[0]" - no
"2844674407370955161[5]" - no
"1844674407470955161[5]" - no
```